# Why does linux have both man and info pages

Tags: linux

Are there historical reasons for this. How should I know which one to check? I usually check in other if I don't find in one.

Comment: If you use emacs you'll have a better time with info docs. Sometimes the info documentation is more up to date than the manpages (especially the libc docs)

Answer (score 5):

The GNU project favors Info pages. Many of the original GNU hackers came from
ITS, and Emacs, which used a system like Info. Manpages originated in Unix, and
used to be favored by traditional Unix hackers.

These days the preferred form of documentation seems to be posts on random
blogs on the Internet, which may or may not be possible to find with a search
engine, but which certainly do get out of date sooner rather than later.

(Sorry, slightly cynical today.)

Comment: LOL ... the 2nd paragraph cracked me up

Comment: Is that a meta-answer? :)

Comment: I thought asking silly questions on stackoverflow was the new man page.

Answer (score 2):

Man is from Unix. Info is a GNU thing.